# resque-web authlogic error when trying to start rails server

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sinatra, authlogic, resque

I am trying to get resque-web server to mount as a rack application as per railscast reque tutorial adding this to routes file :

```
mount Resque::Server, :at => "/resque"
```

when i start up rails server i get this error message :

```
/Users/rick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bundler/gems/authlogic-a087ad0cba3c/lib/authlogic/controller_adapters/sinatra_adapter.rb:50:in `included': undefined method `before' for Sinatra::Request:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Looks like something to do with authlogic?

Does anyone know what this is and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you try removing authlogic from your Gemfile to see if that helps? Could you post your Gemfile?

Answer (score 2):

I've faced the same issue with authlogic and sinatra. If Sinatra declared, authlogic mixes Implementaion module (see lib/authlogic/controller_adapters/sinatra_adapter.rb).
When implementation included it tries to call private method :before on Sinatra::Request class.
:before method somehow added using Sinatra::Delegator.

Long story short - issue has gone after I removed old authlogic gem (2.1.6)
So the answer is to use the most recent authlogic version.